# MVC RedirectToAction not finding my method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

New to MVC and having trouble trying to "Logout" of my site. I have a LogOn() method and view that comes up first to show the Log On page. After I log on then I go to a another page with a button to log out. (note: this is not likely directly related to logging in/out. that is just the story I'm working on)

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="GlobalNavbarPrimary" ID="Content3">
<a href="<%= Url.Action("SignOut","Account") %>" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
</asp:Content>
```

When I press the button then it correctly finds my SignOut method. However, after I logout I try to run a redirect to go back to the LogOn action. I'm not understanding why my LogOn method is not run/found. Here are my LogOn methods and my SignOut method.

```
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string sourceIp = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UserHostAddress))
                sourceIp = Request.UserHostAddress;

            try
            {
                XX.User user = new XX.User();
                XX.SessionKey sk = null;

                sk = user.Logon(model.EmailAddress, model.Password, sourceIp);

                Session[MyAuthorizeAttribute.MySessionKeyName] = sk.Value;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Message");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(ex.Message, "Fatal Error");
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult SignOut()
    {
        CM.User user = new CM.User(Key);
        user.Logout(Key);

        // This does not go to the LogOn action!!!!!
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
```

What is also troubling is that the address bar shows http://localhost:1159/#/Account/SignOut, whereas I was expecting to see http://localhost:1159/#/Account/LogOn (or ....//localhost:1159/)

Any insight (or suggestions for debugging strategies) would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I removed jQuery-mobile from my master page then it works as expected. I had seen some strange things, such as the source of the page (View Source) not matching what I was looking at (actually showing the source of a different page) - an impossibility, so I thought.

I'll have to look at jQuery-mobile closer. I know it is in beta, so perhaps I just hit a known issue.

Comment: Update to jQuery-mobile beta 2 fixed the problem.